# Trying to get property 'id' of non-object Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

this is my route page

```php
Route::get("/customize/profile/{id}", [CustomizeController::class, 'detail'])->name('customize_detail');
```

### here is blade page

```php
<a href="{{ route("customize_detail", [ $item->id ]) }}" title="{{ $item->case_title }}" class="img_scale"> </a>
```

### and this is my controller

```php
    public function detail(Cases $case, $id)
    {
        $caseTable = $case->with('lights');
        $cases = $caseTable->where('id', $id)->first();

        /*foreach ($lights as $light) {
            dd($light);
        }*/
        $cases->case_center_img = json_decode($cases->case_center_img, true);
        return view('customize', compact('cases', ));
    }
```

result is Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

what is the problem  and how to figure it out?

Comment: Welcome to SO .... what is `$item`, where is it supposed to come from?

Comment: $item comes from  @foreach($cases as $item)

Comment: well that stuff should be in your question, don't you think?

Comment: right, my bad..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$item` is not an object, so you cannot refer to its members, like `$item->id`. If `$item` should have been an object, then you will need to take a look why it's not an object. It is highly probable that you have a loop, where `$item` is the iterator and you attempt to refer to it outside the loop body.

Comment: yes, $item comes from a loop, but the url of error page is /customize/profile/8; it proves {{$item->id}} can get id rightly?

Comment: @DonQuixote in the loop, yes. Outside the loop, no. You have some reference to it outside the loop somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

`$cases` is a single Model instance, not a Collection of models. You are calling `first` which would return the first, 1. It could also return `null` but not in this case or the `foreach` loop would error about trying to iterate `null`.

If you iterate a Model instance you are getting its public properties, which are not objects.

You should not be trying to iterate a Model instance.